# Using Flask in a virtualenv with Pyenv

Tags: python, flask, python-venv, pyenv

Im coming back to learning Flask after doing some tutorials a few months back. I have Python 2.7 installed on my Mac but last time I installed & used Python 3 also using Pynv and I also learned how to create and use virtualenvs.

Im trying to run a small Flask app in a virtualenv with Python3 and getting 'ImportError: No module named 'flask'' error. From what I can tell the problem is that I have Flask installed under Python 2.7 as I get this when I run 'pip install flask' from within my venv:

```
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in    ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

However when I run 'pyenv local' with venv activated it tells me its 3.4.3, if I then run 'python my_app.py' Flask works just fine but when I run 'python3 my_app.py' I get the 'no module named flask' error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the toolchain for the same version: Having Flask installed for python 2 won't make it usable for python 3.

Create your virtualenv with the python 3 version (venv-py3, probably), and install packages with version 3 of pip (pip3, probably).

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything wrong. When pyenv activates the virtual environment it points 'python' to the virtualenv python executable but not 'python3'.

You can confirm this by performing these commands:

```
which python3
which python
```

Comment: ok thanks, yes 'which python' returns my venv PATH, so what do I need to do here to set Python3 to the venv and also be able to have Flask work there?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood, if you run:

    which pip && 
    which pip3

Do either point at your virtualenv? If they do then just use that pip command and 'python'.